# How to boot Windows 8 after installing Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: grub2, windows-8

My computer cannot load Windows 8 using GRUB after the installation of Ubuntu 12.10. When I select Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1) it takes the user back to GRUB OS-selection screen. How to recover back?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [repair disk](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/startup-repair) of windows you can insert, boot and select startup repair.

and if you have windows installation disk, insert and boot it and then repair the windows.

Someone told that [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can help.